# How can I make SublimeText version 4's autocomplete behave like version 3?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext, revert, user-preferences, sublimetext4

I recently, too-trustingly, upgraded my Sublime Text 3 to Version 4 (Build 4107). Now auto complete behaves completely differently. It now has a **pop-up** from which I must select a choice - before I would just hit tab and it would choose the best option for me (I could then tab again to try for a better answer).

A concrete example: before, when I typed a word with a typo, for example "questino", I could, with my cursor directly after the o, hit tab and it would correct it to "question" automatically. Now it doesn't do that - now it would pop up a list of any longer words, such as "questions" and "questioned", and then I would have to arrow to one of them and hit enter. It wouldn't even give me "question" as an option - I would have to backspace over the n and then hit tab in order to get a popup that included that word, because not only is the popup annoying, with it requiring multiple additional keystrokes, but autocorrect no longer corrects to a word of the same length as my currently misspelled word, only to longer ones.

There are a lot of options in Preferences, including: auto_complete, auto_complete_size_limit, auto_complete_delay, auto_complete_selector, auto_complete_triggers, auto_complete_commit_on_tab, auto_complete_with_fields, auto_complete_cycle, auto_complete_use_index, auto_complete_use_history, auto_complete_preserve_order, auto_complete_trailing_symbols, and more.

Does anyone know the precise set of preferences to make it behave exactly like it used to? Or maybe there is a package that fixes it? Or maybe my next step will be reverting to the previous version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can get right now appears to be:

```json
    "auto_complete": false,
    "tab_completion": true,
    "mini_auto_complete": true,
```

This is still different from how ST3 works. Tab will fill in only a single value, pressing tab again will not toggle between options, but it won't have the distracting popup.

[Background context](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/making-tab-completion-in-st4-like-st3/58112/5) on the forum. Hopefully this answer will be quickly invalidated by an update or plugin.

Comment: Thank you! This is much better. I thought I'd try adding "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true, but that didn't seem to make a difference so I left it off.

Comment: I reverted to using version 3 and I am happy again.